# Python scrape with multi variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to scrape a handful of data points from two websites for an array of stock tickers. For example:

For array: AAPL, FB, AMZN, ...

1) Extract: 'Dividend Yield Range, Past 5 Years - Average' value from https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/dividend_yield (AAPL being the variable)

2) Extract: 'PE Ratio Range, Past 5 Years - Average' value from https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/pe_ratio (AAPL being the variable)

3) Extract: 'Book/sh' AND 'LT Debt/Eq' value from https://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL (AAPL being the variable)

Output to CSV in format:

Value1, Value2, Value3... for column headers

AAPL,T,MMM... for row headers

I've started from this for action 1)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/dividend_yield', 'https://ycharts.com/companies/T/dividend_yield', 'https://ycharts.com/companies/MMM/dividend_yield']

data = []
for pg in quote_page:
 page = urllib2.urlopen(pg)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
divyield_box = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'col2'})
divyield = divyield_box.text.strip()
data.append((divyield))

with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
 writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 for divyield in data:
    writer.writerow([divyield, datetime.now()])
```

It works but only extracts for the last item of the array?

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you add some code so we know what you've already tried?

Comment: I've added my still incomplete code, thanks for your help

Comment: req = urllib2.Request(quote_page, headers=hdr) -- you're giving this a list when it expects a string.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question, but I'm curious: What made you choose urllib2?

Comment: I’m fairly inexperienced and learning so I looked up sample script to start with, is there a better way?

Comment: @p3nd0l0 It might be a good idea to split the question into different parts. The current way is pretty broad and you might not get a good solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my starting point was here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/ is that good ?

Comment: I've started from scratch but the first issue is it's not going through the array

Answer (score 0):

Try simplified_scrapy's solution

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/dividend_yield', 'https://ycharts.com/companies/T/dividend_yield', 'https://ycharts.com/companies/MMM/dividend_yield']

data = []
for pg in quote_page:
  page = req.get(pg)
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(page)
  divyield = doc.getElement('td',attr='class',value='col2').text
  # divyield = doc.select('td.col2>text()')
  data.append((divyield))
print (data)
```

Result:

```
[u'0.95%', u'5.34%', u'3.18%']
```

Here are more examples of simplified_scrapy [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo)

Comment: Thanks, that looks better indeed. How can I populate the quote_page list with the symbols/tickers from another list such as tickers = [‘AAPL’,‘T’,’MMM’, ... ] ?

Comment: Is that so?
tickers = ['AAPL','T','MMM']
quote_page = ['https://ycharts.com/companies/{}/dividend_yield'.format(ticker) for ticker in tickers]